# query_post problem

Tags: categories, query-posts

I am running query_post with the following arguments,

```
<?php $args = array(
'category'        => $cat,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'blog',
'post_status'     => 'publish' );
```

?>

$cat = 7 in this instance, it should be returning 1 posts, but it is returning all my posts if they are in any category.

Comment: check the docu for category query parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       // Category should be 'cat'
    <?php
 $args = array( 'cat' => $cat, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'blog', 'post_status' => 'publish' );

        ?>
```